# Post data from html form to mysqli database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, mysqli

I have created an html form and I have been trying to send the data the users are going to fill in the form to a mysqli database I created.
I have created the database and created 6 columns for the 6 fields my form has. 
I wrote the following php code to perform the job but it doesn't seem to work...

```
    <?php 
    //get the form elements and store them in variables
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $postal = $_POST['postal'];
    $acceptance = $_POST['acceptance'];

    //establish connection
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'db_user', 'db_password' , 'db_name', 'db_socket'); 
    //on connection failure, throw an error
    if(!$con) {  
    die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error()); 
    } 

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO db_table1 ( firstname, lastname, email, postal, phone, acceptance ) 
VALUES ( $_POST[firstname], $_POST[lastname], $_POST[email], $_POST[postal], $_POST[phone], $_POST[acceptance] )' ; 

    if ($sql) {
        echo 'Success';
    }
    else {
        die ('Error');
    }

    $mysqli->close();

    //Redirects to the specified page
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/success");
    ?>
```

Could you help me out? Where is the problem and nothing gets into the db?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code

```
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO db_table1 ( firstname, lastname, email, postal, phone,acceptance ) VALUES ( "'.$firstname.'","'.$lastname.'","'.$email.'","'.$postal.'","'.$phone.'","'.$acceptance.'", )' ;
    $response= mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

This adds the `mysqli_query`. In short you built the string to be used for the query, but didn't do the actual query.

Answer (score 0):

There's a multitude of problems here, but the most obvious is you define a SQL query as a string, test that this string exists, which it obviously will, and then call it a day. They say it's the thought that counts, but when it comes to programming you'll have to be more explicit.

You need to actually *execute* the query. With `mysqli` this is a multi-step process: Prepare, bind, execute. After that you do a fetch if necessary. As always, [have the documentation open if you're unfamiliar with how to do all of this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). It's an essential step in understanding something.

Update it to this where using the object-oriented notation makes things a lot more clear:

```
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'db_user', 'db_password' , 'db_name', 'db_socket');

$stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO db_table1 (firstname, lastname, email, postal, phone, acceptance) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)');

$stmt->bind_param('ssssss',
  $_POST[firstname], $_POST[lastname],
  $_POST[email], $_POST[postal],
  $_POST[phone], $_POST[acceptance]
);

$stmt->execute();
```

Don't forget that in PHP strings using single quotes like `'$this'` do not interpolate their variables but double-quoted ones like `"$this"` will. That's another problem in your original code.

Answer (score -1):

there is a problem in your query string
Please note that in php if a string is surrounded by single quotes(as you have done) it is taken as it is without interpolating any variables

If you string contains variables you should surround it with double quote

So replace the single quotes with double quotes this will include the post variables into your query and to test this you can print your  $sql variable.

Now although the code will work but its not the best way to use mysqli. use prepossessed queries the standard three steps for executing a query in mysqli to actually reap the mysqli benifits as using variables directly into query string makes your code vulnerable to Sql Injection attack

Answer (score -2):

you can also try this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (username, email, password, avater) "
     . "VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password', '$avater_path')";
```

Comment: This is insecure code likely vulnerable to **SQL injection**. Please use prepared statements instead. Also, please name the columns in the same way that the OP does.